# Converting a large floating-point number to a single-line string

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation

When I feed a large (or small) enough floating-point number to `ToString`, it produces a two-line string, with the first line containing only the exponent of 10:

```
In := ToString[12345.^6]
Out :=           24
       3.53954 10
```

This creates problems because it's very counterintuitive when written to a log file. For example `ToString[{51.5^7, 2, 3, 12345.^6}]` would be written out as

```
           11                  24\n{9.60839 10  , 2, 3, 3.53954 10  }
```

which is practically unrecognizable for what it is, especially when inserted in the middle of other output. I would like to see output like

```
{9.60839E+11, 2, 3, 3.53954E+24}
```

or, if not that, I'd be fine with something like

```
{9.60839*^11, 2, 3, 3.53954*^24}
```

What can I do to print out floating-point numbers in a format suitable for single-line output?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Admittedly hackish, but you could use

```
numbers = RandomReal[10^10, 3]

ToString[ToString[#, CForm] & /@ numbers]
```

or

```
ToString[ToString[#, FortranForm] & /@ numbers]
```

It gives

```
{3.672422352722051e9, 8.491123505444411e9, 1.7587409493599138e9}
```

Mathematica usually likes to wrap long lines.  This won't happen here because by default `ToString` uses `PageWidth -> Infinity`

Comment: Analogously: `ToString[ToString[#, FortranForm] & /@ numbers]`.

Comment: @JM Edited it into the answer, it's always good to draw attention to more functions.

Answer (score 17):

Just ask for it in `InputForm`:

```
In[1]:= ToString[12345.^6, InputForm]

Out[1]= 3.539537889086625*^24
```

Answer (score 16):

There is already a built in function to handle this — it's called [`ScientificForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScientificForm.html). You can get the output you desire as:

```
ScientificForm[12345.^6, NumberFormat -> (#1 <> "E" <> #3 &)] // ToString
Out[1]= 3.53954E24
```

`StringForm` only affects the display, so to export it correctly as a string to a log file, you'll have to wrap it in `ToString` like I've done. If you're only going to display it, you can drop that.

Answer (score 6):

I came upon this question when trying to add a number in scientific notation to a string in the label of a plot, which requires that (or at least looks better if) the number is written with the exponents properly typeset (i.e. like $1.453\times 10^4$). This is not really what's in the question but it's not covered exaclty in any of the answers so far and this is probably the best place to document it.

This can be done by applying [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToString.html)'s option to format as [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraditionalForm.html) *after* applying the [`ScientificForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScientificForm.html) command. Thus,

```
"number=" <> ToString[ScientificForm[14531.456456, 4], TraditionalForm]
```

will produce

> [image]

with a [`String`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/String.html) head which can be fed to labels or combined with other strings.