# Convert floating point numbers to string like sprintf/fprintf?

Tags: export, output-formatting

I am trying to export some floating point numbers into a csv/txt file. I would like to have a efficient way to control the space between numbers as well as the accuracy of the numbers, as we do in C:

```
 fprintf(
   fname, "%9.5f, %9.5f, %9.5f, %9.5f, %d\n", 
   y[i][1], y[i][2], y[i][3], y[i][4], d[i]
 );
```

Here `"%9.5f"` is exactly what I want to implement in Mathematica. I searched for hours and can not get a good solution. `NumberForm` and `PaddedForm` only change the printing format, while others like `SetAccuracy` does not control the spaces. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: I just linked to my sprintf-like implementation as an answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246849/7936

Answer (score 2):

The [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html)option [`NumberPadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberPadding.html) does exactly what you want:

```
StringTemplate["``, ``"] @@ (
  NumberForm[#, {9, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}] & /@ {3.1, 5.1}
)

(* "    3.10000,     5.10000" *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica has no real `sprintf`- or `fprintf`-equivalents. Others have asked about the problem.

1. [Can StringTemplate be extended to offer printf-like formatting capabilities?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54541/41569)
2. [sprintf() or close equivalent, or re-implementation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/973/41569)

We can, however, simulate `sprintf` format with Mathematica functions and a bit of manipulation. Here are some sample values to demonstrate the problems with direct use of `NumberForm`.

```
samples = {1.123, 12.12345, -12.12345, 123.12345,
  1234.12345, -123.12345, -123.123455};
```

This is the expected result for `samples` using `sprintf` and `%9.5f` format.

> ```
> 1.123       "  1.12300"
> 12.12345    " 12.12345"
> -12.12345   "-12.12345"
> 123.12345   "123.12345"
> 1234.12345  "1234.12345"
> -123.12345  "-123.12345"
> -123.123455 "-123.12346"
> ```

Let's try to create the same result in Mathematica. Unfortunately, `NumberForm` does not duplicate `sprintf`.

```
numberform = 
  ToString@NumberForm[#, {9, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}] & /@ samples;
```

The length of the `NumberForm` strings is 11, but the length of `sprintf` strings is 9 before overflow. A fix is to trim one or two leading blanks from the `NumberForm` strings with `StringTrim`. Here's a comparison of `sprintf`, using `NumberForm` alone, and combining `StringTrim[#, RegularExpression["^ {1,2}"]]` with `NumberForm`.

> ```
> sprintf       NumberForm     StringTrim
> "  1.12300"   "    1.12300"  "  1.12300"
> " 12.12345"   "   12.12345"  " 12.12345"
> "-12.12345"   "  -12.12345"  "-12.12345"
> "123.12345"   "  123.12345"  "123.12345"
> "1234.12345"  " 1234.12345"  "1234.12345"
> "-123.12345"  " -123.12345"  "-123.12345"
> "-123.12346"  " -123.12346"  "-123.12346"
> ```

---

To simulate how `fprintf` would work with some sample data, first, convert the floating-point values in `y` to `sprintf` format. Convert the value in `d` to a string with `ToString[IntegerPart[d[[i]]]]`. Next, separate the `sprintf` strings with comma and a space: `", "`. Here are some sample values for `y` and `d`.

```
SeedRandom[1]
y = RandomReal[{-99, 99}, {1, 4}];
d = RandomInteger[10, 4];
i = 1;

floats = StringTrim[#, RegularExpression["^ {1,2}"]] & /@
 (ToString@NumberForm[#, {9, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}] & /@ 
   y[[i]]);

s = StringJoin[
   Riffle[Flatten@{floats, ToString[IntegerPart[d[[i]]]]}, ", "]
   ];

s // InputForm
```

The result, `s`, simulates the output of `sprintf("%9.5f, %9.5f, %9.5f, %9.5f, %d", ...)`.

> ```
> " 62.84312, -76.93892,  57.32615, -61.81498, 3"
> ```

Finally, save the formatted values to a text file.

```
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "fname.txt"], s]
```