# How do I pad numbers to the left so that all are the same length?

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting

I have a list of numbers like

```
{-6, 1, 3, 23}
```

and want to get a list of strings, all of the same length, with zeros padding on the left as needed, like

```
{"-6", "01", "03", "23"}
```

The closest I can get following the documentation is with something like

```
NumberForm[{-6, 1, 3, 23}, 1, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]
```

which (astonishingly) produces

```
{"-6", "01", "03", "023"}
```

How I can simply get my strings to all be the same length, padded as needed with zeros?

Comment: What do you desire for the first entry:  "-06" or "0-6" or "-006"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: "-6", as indicated: all the same length.

Comment: Oh... it was unclear whether you wanted all strings to have the length 3 (in this case)... as in "023".  Let me work on this....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Length 2.

Comment: `IntegerString` may come in handy.

Comment: What in case of: `{-6, 123}`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius  Do you want every and all strings to be of length 2 in every case (not just in your example)?  You never want to apply the transformation to numbers such as *123* or *-11*?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Just like the example. Never more than one digit negative numbers and never more than two digit positives.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of [10.1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn101.html) this is built in to *Mathematica* with [`StringPadLeft`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringPadLeft.html):

```
StringPadLeft[#,2,"0"]&@*ToString/@{-6,1,3,23}
```

> {"-6", "01", "03", "23"}

Comment: Could you please elucidate on the meaning of `&@*`?

Comment: @Oscillon [Composition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[nF]
nF = With[{l = #, p = #2}, NumberForm[l, p, SignPadding -> True, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}, 
         NumberFormat -> (StringTake[#1, -(p + 1)] &)]] &;

nF[{-6, 1, 3, 23}, 1]
(* {-6, 01, 03, 23} *)

nF[{-6, 1, 3, 23, 123}, 2]
(* {-06, 001, 003, 023, 123} *)
```

Note: You can also use `PaddedForm` instead of `NumberForm`.

Answer (score 4):

Taking under consideration your assumptions:

```
StringTake["0" <> ToString[#], -2] & /@ {-6, 1, 3, 23}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
If[StringLength@# == 1, "0" <> #, #] &@*ToString /@ {-6, 1, 3, 23}
```

Another way:

```
StringJoin@*(ToString /@ PadLeft[#, 2] &)@*Characters@*ToString /@ {-6, 1, 3, 23}
```

Comment: So there's no built-in way to do this? Any idea what the reasoning behind the way `NumberForm` works could possibly be? I really don't understand the philosophy behind the *Mathematica* language design (c.f.: `[str(n).zfill(2) for n in numbers]`).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Take a look at the newest solution. There is a built in function, but in order to use it we must first convert our string into a list.

Comment: So the second solution is incomplete.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Argh, I forgot to convert it back into a string. Now it's less elegant; I'd go with the first option. I'd go with it anyway because it's easy to understand; if you look at it in 6 months you will still know what it does.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I'm still puzzled what (if any) design philosophy could have lead to this sort of thing.  `[str(n).zfill(2) for n in numbers]` is not only something I'll understand in 6 months, but something that I can remember to recreate in 6 months (or years).

Comment: Whats the "@*"? New in 10 I suppose?  Anyway another way to write basically the same thing: `StringJoin @@ PadLeft[Characters@ToString@#, 2, "0"] & /@ {-6, 1, 3, 
  23}`

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius In some languages strings are simply arrays of characters. In this case it makes sense to handle padding of both strings and arrays with the same function. Strings in Mathematica is not implemented as a list, in fact strings are "atomic". I can only speculate that this has something to do with it.

Comment: @george2079 Nice version, I forgot about the third argument of `PadLeft`. It's just a shorthand for `Composition`.

Comment: I had the same problem and I don't understand why `PaddedForm[5, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]` gives `005`, `PaddedForm[15, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]` gives `015` and then surprisingly: `PaddedForm[125, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]` gives `0125`. Thanks for the solutions anyway!

Answer (score 2):

just for fun..we can define a `zfill` function

```
 zfill[n_, f_String: "0"] := 
      Function[{s}, 
        StringJoin[ConstantArray[f, Max[0, n - StringLength[s]]], s]];
```

then the operation is quite similar to your python expression:

```
 zfill[2] /@ ToString /@ {-6, 1, 3, 23}
```

> {"-6", "01", "03", "23"}

Comment: I find this a good one!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that is loosely based upon [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)'s previous [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76359/76328).  The below solution has been generalized to also handle decimal numbers and scientific form.  Your example number list only contained small integers, but others who find this post may find the generalization useful.

The code:

```
AltNumberFormat[n_, f___, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{NumberForm, "AltPadding" -> ""}]] := With[{
   IsExtraPad = 
    MatchQ@First[OptionValue@NumberPadding /. Automatic -> {""}],
   altPad = OptionValue@"AltPadding"
   },
  NumberForm[
   N@n, f, FilterRules[{opts}, Options@NumberForm],
   NumberFormat -> Function[{m, b, e}, With[
      {s = 
        StringReplace[m, StartOfString ~~ _?IsExtraPad -> altPad]},
      If[e == "", s, Row[{s, b^e}, "\[Times]"]]
      ]]]]
```

Usage is exactly the same as regular `NumberForm`, with the addition of an extra `AltPadding` option.  This would usually be used if you wanted to pad with leading zeros (without the extra zeros!) but still get your numbers to left-align, by padding positive numbers with leading spaces.

Test cases:

```
hdr = Prepend[
   Item[#, BaseStyle -> Bold, Background -> LightBlue] & /@ {"Input", 
     "Format", "Padding", "Output"}];

Row@Map[Grid[hdr@#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, 
       Background -> {{4 -> LightYellow}}] &]@
    Transpose@Flatten[#, 2] &@
 Table[
  {m*n, f, Style[p, ShowStringCharacters -> True], 
   AltNumberFormat[m*n, f, NumberPadding -> p, SignPadding -> True, 
    AltPadding -> " "]},
  {f, {Unevaluated@Sequence[], 4, {6, 3}}},
  {n, {0.1, 1.2, 1.23456, 123456, 1.2*10^15, 1.23456*10^15}},
  {m, {-1, 1}},
  {p, {Automatic, {"", "0"}, {"0", "0"}}}
  ]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `sprintf` that I describe [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246849/7936), you can do `Map[sprintf["%02i", #] &, {-6, 1, 3, 23}]` to get `{"-6", "01", "03", "23"}`.