# StringForm with named arguments

Tags: string-manipulation, replacement

[`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html) with named arguments

In python, this is possible:

example:

```
a = "{x}, {y}".format(x=5, y=12)
print(a)
```

result:

> 5, 12

In *Mathematica*, I used

```
StringForm ["``,``",5,12]
```

but I couldn't use named arguments.

Is there any way to do this in *Mathematica*? like a :

```
StringForm ["`x`,`y`",x->5, y->12]
```

Comment: ``StringTemplate[" `x` , `y`"][<|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>]`` or ``TemplateApply["`a`,`b`", <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]``?

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/970/10397).

Answer (score 2):

```
sfWithNamedArguments = TemplateApply[#, Association[MapAt[SymbolName,{##2}, {All, 1}]]]&;

sfWithNamedArguments["`q`,`r`", q -> 10, r -> 5]
```

> "10,5"

The following also works in version 9 (where `TemplateApply` is not available):

```
ClearAll[sF]
sF = StringReplace[#, "`" ~~ a_ ~~ "`" :> IntegerString[ToExpression[a] /. {##2}]] &;

sF["`x` then `y` then `x` again", x -> 5, y -> 12]
```

> "5 then 12 then 5 again"

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica and python don't have much in common in the area you are asking about. You might consider

```
 Row[{x, ", ", y}] /. {x -> 5, y -> 12}
```

which displays as

[image: row]

but is not a string.

```
% // FullForm
```

> `FullForm[Row[{5, ", ", 12}]]`

If you need a string rather than a display form, use

```
(Row[{x, ", ", y}] /. {x -> 5, y -> 12}) // ToString
```