# Using printf for formatted print

Tags: output-formatting, printing

My data is

```
data = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0.469258}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 0.}, {1, 1, 1, 3, -0.000123615}}
```

On linux-like systems there is a `printf` routine to make formatted print. How can I use this function from mathematica in order to obtain the formatted text file with 5 columns and 3 rows with a given format.

For instance with `printf "%3i %3i %3i %3i %10.6f\n"` I am expecting

```
  1   1   1   1   0.469258
  1   1   1   2   0.000000
  1   1   1   3  -0.000124
```

Currently I doing

```
file = "a.dat";
If[FileExistsQ[file], DeleteFile[file]]
cmd = "printf \"%3i %3i %3i %3i %10.6f\\n\"";
Do[
 args = StringRiffle[ToString[#] & /@ s];
 Run[StringRiffle[{cmd, args, ">>", file}]];
 , {s, data}]
```

But is it an idiomatic method? Will it fail in some cases, like for other variable types or too long strings? Is there a better way?

Comment: Would `Export`ing the data as a `"Table"` (perhaps using appropriate `"FieldSeparators"` as an option) work for you?

Comment: Try: Export["filename", data, "Table"]

Comment: @MarcoB With `Export`ing plus `"FieldSeparators"` you almost there, but formatting is difficult. I doubt that MA can *exactly* conform all the rules that `printf`is using, or am I wrong? I am not after the speed, but more after the control, accuracy and predictability of output.

Comment: @DanielHuber Tried, is precise format control possible? I need output *identically* equal to that of `printf`.

Comment: I can not say as I do not know what printf exactly does. Look up `Export` in the manual and then to try it.

Comment: @yarchik can you explain what the formatting rules mean in your printf expression? I would think those could be reproduced with `NumberForm`, `DecimalForm`, `PaddedForm`, ... . See also [Display of numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DisplayOfNumbers.html) and [Output format for numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#20024).

Comment: @MarcoB I think, I was not fully clear in my post: my aim is not to reproduce the functionality of `printf`with MA methods. I am rather asking how to properly transfer the data to an external utility so that no data loss occurs. I do not know what is the maximum string length that can be transferred to `Run`.  However, I am rather intrigued with your idea. To answer your question, I need to update my post. This will take time because there are too many [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) and cases. I am not the developer of `printf`, so I know at best 10% of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sprintf() or close equivalent, or re-implementation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/970/sprintf-or-close-equivalent-or-re-implementation)

Comment: @WReach Thank you adding this post to my question. I feel that people are trying to re-invent a wheel... My solution has a lot of advantages, like 100% compatibility, but it needs some expertise in sending the arguments to the shell utility. This is the main focus of the OP.

Comment: I cannot write a full answer at this time, but a couple of suggestions: 1) use `ToString@*CForm` on each argument so that exponentials are written in C syntax instead of _Mathematica_ syntax, 2) if strings are going to be permitted then any characters with special meaning to the shell must be escaped.

Comment: @WReach Thank you for these suggestions, they are indeed very valuable and exactly in the direction I was thinking of. So, I encourage you to write a full answer when you have time.